# Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException The parameter "..." must be defined

Tags: symfony

when I execute a command in production (only) environnement

I have the error

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
>     The parameter "..." must be defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

whether this concerns only prod you simply directly delete the contents of the app / cache / prod

```
rm -rf app/cache/prod/*
```